# How can I pass URI to API using AsyncTask in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to send a PDF file via Web API using below method:

```
public static <function> JSONObject uploadFile(String url, Context context, JSONObject jsondata, String imagepath) {
        sJsonObj = null;
        sb = null;

        try {
            sUrl = new URL(url);

            sHttpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sUrl.openConnection();
            sHttpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(sTimeout);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(sTimeout);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("fileName", imagepath);
            sHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");


            sPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(sHttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

            sPrintWriter.append(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY)
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"body\"")
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append(jsondata.toString())
                    .append(LINE_END)

                    .append(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY)
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileName\"; filename=\"" + new File(imagepath).getAbsoluteFile() + "\"")
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append("Content-Type: "
                            + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(imagepath))
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary")
                    .append(LINE_END)
                    .append(LINE_END);

            sPrintWriter.flush();

            FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(imagepath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                sHttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            fileStream.close();

            sPrintWriter.append(LINE_END);
            sPrintWriter.append(TWO_HYPHENS);
            sPrintWriter.append(BOUNDARY);
            sPrintWriter.append(TWO_HYPHENS);
            sPrintWriter.flush();
            sHttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream().close();

            if (true) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sHttpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                reader.close();

                sJsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sHttpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return sJsonObj;
    }
```

If you carefully look the param of uploadFile method, then you'll get that the last param is `filePath`,

After searching from last 2 days continuously on Stack overflow, I found that I can't get a filePath, in some of the newer Android version.

And my app is supporting from **Api level 21 to 30**, So everyone is suggesting that try via passing URI only.

Now, In this uploadFile method, if I'll try to change last param from String to Uri, there so many places compiler error is coming. Now I'm not getting that What should I change in this method?

Can anyone please post an answer with some modification with same method, that will be really appreciated.

FileNotFound Exception is coming, If I'll pass uri.getPath

Answer (score -2):

Could you try? I provide some code:

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android